# Prove that the automorphism group of any non-commutative group is acyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If a group H is non-commutative, Aut(H) can be commutative or non-commutative. So we can't prove it in this way.

Is it possible to prove that Inn(H) is acyclic? Or are there any other solutions?

Comment: Hint: The group of inner automorphisms is isomorphic to $G/Z(G)$.

Comment: Hint: find the  inner automorphism group of the dihedral groups $D_n$. Consider the two cases, $n$ odd or even.

Comment: @PVanchinathan Why would that help?

Comment: @ Tobias Kildetoft:  One can find out if Inn(G)  is cyclic or not by playing around with this example;  this is an easy family of nonabelian groups.

Comment: If $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is commutative.

Comment: The hints are very useful. Problem solved. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @PVanchinathan Given that it is never cyclic for a nonabelian group, I fail to see why looking at a specific example would help.

Answer (score 1):

Using the hint, you must show that if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic than G is an abelian group. In fact, let $a$ be the generator of $G/Z(G)$. Than you can write every $g\in G$ as $a^h*z$ where $z\in Z(G)$. Than you have 
$$ g*g'=(a^h*z)*(a^k*z')=a^{h+k}*z*z'=a^{k+h}*z*z'=(a^k*z')*(a^h*z)=g'*g $$

so $G$ is an abelian group.